# Calculation of surface integral

Tags: integration, surfaces, surface-integrals

## Question

Calculate 
$ \int x+z ~dS $ on the domain bounded by the first octant and the plane $x+y+z=1$

## Attempt

$$ \int_S x+z~dS = \sqrt3\int_0^1 \int_0^{y-1} x +z ~dxdy 
$$
Since on the $xy$ plane $z=0$ then 
$$ \sqrt3\int_0^1 \int_0^{y-1} x +z ~dxdy = \sqrt3\int_0^1 \int_0^{y-1} x ~dxdy = A
$$

## Attempt 2

$$ \int_S x+z~dS = \sqrt3\int_0^1 \int_0^{y-1} x +z ~dxdy = \sqrt3\int_0^1 \int_0^{y-1} x+1-y-x ~dxdy =\sqrt3\int_0^1 \int_0^{y-1} 1-y ~dxdy = B
$$

However $A\neq B $. So can somebody please tell me what mistake I am making in any of the methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the integral we need to divide it in the 4 boundaries

- $S_1 \quad x=0$
- $S_2 \quad y=0$
- $S_3 \quad z=0$
- $S_4 \quad x+y+z=1$

then

$$ \int_S x+z~dS = \int_{S_1} z~dS+\int_{S_2} x+z~dS+\int_{S_3} x~dS+\int_{S_4} (1-y)~dS $$

You attempt 2 seems indeed to be correct.

Comment: Can you also tell me what was the flaw in my criteria?